# how to select specific json data and store it into an array in Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am facing issue to store category SINGLES related data into an array and then use this array to display show data.Basically, I just want to store data that is only belong to category "SINGLES" from json file that I named it "data.json" into an array.Can anyone help me please. I would really appreciate that.
Index.html

```
<div id="app">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6" v-for="model in jsonSingleData">
 <div class="beeton-models-box">
<div class="image-holder">
</div>
<div class="text-box">
<h3>{{model.title}}</h3>
<p>{{model.bedrooms}}</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

script.js 

var vm = new Vue({

el:'#app',
data:{

    jsonSingleData:[]



},
created:function(){
   this.fetchDataAll();


},

methods:{


fetchDataAll: function(){

    var url="data.json";
    axios.get(url)
    .then(function(res){

     res.data.models.forEach(single=>{

            if(single.category=='SINGLES')
            {


                vm.jsonSingleData=single;
                console.log(single);



            }


        });

    });

}
```

The below is my json file.
data.json

```
{
    "models": [
      {
        "title": "IRIS",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "SINGLES",
        "bedrooms": 3

      },
      {
        "title": "LILAC",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "DOUBLE",
        "bedrooms": 4

      },
      {
        "title": "ASTER",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "SINGLES",
        "bedrooms": 4

      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You're already trying to do this. What problem do you have?

Comment: @EstusFlask I am not able to stored SINGLES related data into an array.

Comment: This doesn't describe the problem. You're not able because?... If there are errors, they should be listed because they could give a clue what's wrong. Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . The question should have clear problem statement. The code clearly has bugs as the answer notes but it's unclear if they exist in original code and are the only problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your method is missing some points. Also, you are missing a `}` at the end.

Try this:

```
fetchDataAll: function(){
    var vm = this;
    var url="data.json";
    axios.get(url)
    .then(function(res){

     res.data.models.forEach((single)=>{

            if(single.category=='SINGLES')
            {

                vm.jsonSingleData.push(single);
                console.log(single);

            }

        });

    });

}
```